# How do I create a menu which looks like this

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE6BC.png)

I don't want to use the PSD images. I would prefer using icons from some package like FontAwesome and have the backgrounds/css generated in CSS.

Comment: i am using this codes is give this link http://codepen.io/suez/pen/vAais i not get the results

Comment: You should consider posting an actual question someone can answer. Expecting someone to guess what you've tried and how it failed won't get you a solution

Comment: i am new to HTML that why asking like,i am not able to post the code here

Comment: then it's not a programming question. "how do I do this" or "how can I make this" is not a fault to be fixed

Comment: In this link have some code, i am make use that code

Comment: if you clear that fault and post the code here i will use that

Comment: there is no fault. there is no programming question, you're asking someone to make a change to an existing working example someone else has made. This website isn't about doing other peoples jobs for them http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN CHECK LIVE DEMO HERE http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/6148/

```
<style>
                @import "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

                body {
                  background: #39D;
                }

                .circular-menu {
                  width: 250px;
                  height: 250px;
                  margin: 0 auto;
                  position: relative;
                }

                .circle {
                  width: 250px;
                  height: 250px;
                  opacity: 0;

                  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
                  -moz-transform: scale(0);
                  transform: scale(0);

                  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
                  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
                  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
                }

                .open.circle {
                  opacity: 1;

                  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                  -moz-transform: scale(1);
                  transform: scale(1);
                }

                .circle a {
                  text-decoration: none;
                  color: white;
                  display: block;
                  height: 40px;
                  width: 40px;
                  line-height: 40px;
                  margin-left: -20px;
                  margin-top: -20px;
                  position: absolute;
                  text-align: center;

                }

                .circle a:hover {
                  color: #eef;
                }

                .menu-button {
                  position: absolute;
                  top: calc(50% - 30px);
                  left: calc(50% - 30px);
                  text-decoration: none;
                  text-align: center;
                  color: #444;
                  border-radius: 50%;
                  display: block;
                  height: 40px;
                  width: 40px;
                  line-height: 40px;
                  padding: 10px;
                  background: #dde;
                }

                .menu-button:hover {
                  background-color: #eef;
                }

                /* Author stuff */
                h1.author {
                  text-align:center;
                  color: white;
                  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                  font-weight: 300;
                }

                h1.author a {
                  color: #348;
                  text-decoration:none;
                }

                h1.author a:hover {
                  color: #ddd;
                } 
                </style>

            <---HTML--->
            <nav class="circular-menu">

              <div class="circle">
                <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
              </div>

              <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

            </nav>
            <---HTML--->


        <---js--->
        <script>
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

        for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
          items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

          items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
        }

        document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
        }
    </script>
        <---js--->
```

Comment: Seriously impressive code!  But I can't believe you bothered writing the entire JS/HTML/CSS for this question.  The user should have at least had a go themselves first, and used SO when he got stuck.